# MongoDB temporary node / mirror

Tags: mongodb, deployment, amazon-ec2

When I have a running MongoDB instance with some data and requests against it, can I start a second instance on another machine, register it as another node in the first instance and all the data is copied to the second node while changes on the first node in the meantime are also mirrored to the second instance? Is that possible?

The context is: I have a single machine deployment with an application and mongodb running on the same instance (Amazon EC2). Its a low budget deployment but I try to have as few downtime as possible. I'd like to change the ec2 instance every week and for that I'd need some sort of mirroring. Is that possible?

Comment: You are asking about [Replica Set's](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replication-introduction/), even if in a temporary context. You are also asking on the wrong site, and should be asking on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) instead.

Comment: Oh, danke für den Hinweis. Ich werde es da nochmal probieren :)